# adobe acrobat XI pro javascript

Tags: adobe, acrobat

i am calling an javascript function when out of focus on the form field. So what i am tying to do is the if i ticked required this field as required field it will have a red border around it, can i write a script to remove the required option when there are value inside the field?

```
var thisValue = this.getField("companyName").value;
var regexLetter = /[A-Z]+$/;
var Icon = "0"; //0 — Error (default) // 1 — Warning // 2 — Question // 3 — Status
var Type = "0"; //0 — OK (default) // 1 — OK, Cancel // 2 — Yes, No // 3 — Yes, No, Cancel
if (thisValue == ""){
    app.alert({
            cMsg:"this is an warning",
            cTitle: "thsi is title",
            nIcon: Icon, 
            nType: Type
        })

} else if(!regexLetter.test(thisValue)){
  app.alert('Type alphanumeric character');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be rather late, but this is how I do it in my documents:

```
var _companyName = this.getField("CompanyName");

    _companyName.required = (_companyName.value === "");
```

You can also impose other dependencies, like:

```
var _companyName = this.getField("CompanyName"),
    _companyLicense = this.getField("CompanyLicense");

    _companyLicense = ((_companyLicense === "")
        && (_companyName !== ""));
```

Having your scripts split into a couple of files could help. I use a "shared" script which contains a vast majority of the logic and the a "specific" script to round of each individual document. Also, make sure when adding the scripts to just name them 1, 2, 3, etc. in the correct order or Acrobat will be stupid. Hope this helps you.